# Trying to install the package libstdc++6:i386 or ia32-libs in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS after 'sudo apt-get update'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Reason I want to install this, is because I am facing an error with avd creation,idea.log shows 'WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder'

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Things I tried tried and failed to make avd creating possible:-

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo rm -R -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
chmod -R 777 ../tools
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++
sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386
```

all i get is:-Package '' has no installation candidate

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs
```

My sources.list:-

```
# See sources.list(5) manpage for more information
# Remember that CD-ROMs, DVDs and such are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
```

This issue is been attended earlier but somehow solutions doesn't seem to work for me in updated package list of ubuntu 16.Please let me know what am i doing wrong or some more information about the error is in need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,hope it works for others as well

visit this website -> https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/
and choose your 'country' and 'release' along with necessary 'branches' and 'updates' and go to end of the page till 'Generate list' button and click it to get your new sources.list

copy the text in 'sources list' text field and open sources.list file in /etc/apt/ in local file system and open in editable mode i.e., in sudo mode to edit, replace the current data with newly copy data and save it

open terminal enter these commands :
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

you are done. Now, just check if the problem with making AVD is gone or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libstdc++6-i386-cross
```

This version of `ibstdc++6-i386-cross` - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (i386) works for me